# Make XML file not accessible by surfing to url

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I'm using XML-files for the settings of my Cakephp-application. (Located in /files/xmlfiles/).
I want this files only be accessible by my application and not by to surfing to it ( www.domain.com/files/xmlfiles/data.xml).

Changing the rights of the file (CHMOD 0600) isn't a solution, I think I could use an httaccess for that, anyone can help me with this? Or another solution?

Thanks in advance,

Aäron

Comment: As long as your XML-file is not in the DocumentRoot of the server, it  won't be accessible by surfing to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <your-ip-adress-of-your-server>
```

or if you want the file only to be accessed by the server its placed on:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

place it within the .htaccess file